# Area covered by particle between it's path and horizontal lines

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

> **Question:** The maximum range of projectile is $R$ and the maximum height attained by the particle is *H*.
>
> If the area covered by the particle between its path and horizontal line is $A$, then $A$ =
>
> 1. $\frac{2}{5}$
> 2. $\frac{2}{3}$
> 3. $\frac{4}{5}$
> 4. $\frac{1}{3}$

I know the formula for maximum range $R$ and maximum height $H$

$R=\frac{U^2}{g}$, $U$ is initial veocity and $g$ is acceleration due to gravity

$$H=\frac{U^2 \sin^2\theta}{2g}$$

I can't find the way to realte this formula with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your particle should follow a parabola, all you need is the formula for the area under a parabola, which is

$A = \frac{2}{3} R\cdot H$

A derivation of this can be found here http://www.math.nmsu.edu/~breakingaway/ebookofcalculus/HandsOnUnitsInvolvingIntegrals/AreaUnderParabola/AreaUnderParabolaWebPage01.html.

Using differential calculus and finding the tangent to any point on a parabola, we can also find $\sin (\theta)$. A derivation of this is given here http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/math99/math99267.htm.